# Getting months in select box

Tags: php, loops

```
<select name="month" id="month" >
    <option value="">Select</option>
    <?php

    for ($i = 0; $i < 12;   $i++) {
    $date_str = date('M', strtotime("+ $i months"));
    echo "<option value=$i>".$date_str ."</option>";

    } ?>
    </select>
```

When I am runnig this code value starting from 0 i want to be start from 1

for eg : value for January    should be "1" . how is it possible ?

Comment: @Rikesh That wont work, because `date('M', strtotime("+ $i months")` in PHP requires the month numbers starting with zero (0).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<select name="month" id="month" >
<option value="">Select</option>
<?php

for ($i = 0; $i < 12; ) {
$date_str = date('M', strtotime("+ $i++ months"));
echo "<option value=$i>".$date_str ."</option>";

} ?>
</select>
```

Moving the ++ to after the strtotime function but before the display will work. You need to leave the last part of the for blank for this to work

Comment: This is correct, but from my point of view a little bit confusing. Would you remember what that code does at a first glance after six month not working on it?

Comment: if you used comments yes - comments in version control or inline php

Comment: <select class="form-control" id="month" name="month" >
     <?php
           for($i = 1 ; $i <= 12 ; $i++){
               if ( $i == $curr_Month ) { $select="selected='selected'"; } else {  $select=""; }
               $month_num = str_pad( $i, 2, 0, STR_PAD_LEFT );
               $month_name = date( 'F', mktime( 0, 0, 0, $i, 1, 2000 ) ); //  (hours , min , secs , month, day , year ) 
               echo "<option $select value='$month_num'> $month_name</option>";

                 }                         
        ?>
 </select>

Answer (score 3):

By adding one (1) to each month' number before output.

```
for( $i = 0; $i < 12; $i++ )
{
    $date_str = date( 'M', strtotime('+ $i months') );
    echo sprintf( '<option value="%d">%s</option>', $i + 1, $date_str );
}
```

BTW: HTML attributes should be written with quotes to prevent failures resulting from spaces.

Comment: @Rikesh its working but January goes down and its starting with Feb

Comment: for ($i = 0; $i < 12;   $i++) {
        $date_str = date('M', strtotime("+ $i months"));
  $new_i = $i+1;
        echo "<option value=$new_i>".$date_str ."</option>";
 }

Comment: This does not work for multiple reasons. Even if I fix some of the syntax to make it work, its output differs based on when you run it. And if you run it on March 30, 2017, you'll get duplicate month values.

Answer (score 0):

for ($i = 1; $i <= 12;   $i++)

Comment: Because it's wrong with the OP's code. See my comment to Rikesh on the question…