# Birthdate values in php html

Tags: php, html

Good day everyone I have a little problem with this code. All of my month values are "January". Any help would be very much appreciated, thank you.

```
Birthday: 
<select name="month">
<option value="0">Select Month</option>
<?php
    for( $m = 1; $m <= 12; $m++ ) {
        $num = str_pad( $m, 2, 0, STR_PAD_LEFT );
        $month = date( 'F', mktime( 0, 0, 0, $m + 1, 0, 0, 0 ) );
        ?>
            <option value="<?php echo $num; ?>"><?php echo $month; ?></option>
        <?php
    }
?>
</select>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting months in select box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14195564/getting-months-in-select-box)

Comment: Did you check the error? `mktime() expects at most 6 parameters, 7 given`

Comment: There's a `0` to many.

Comment: @0stone0 is right replace with this ` $month = date( 'F', mktime( 0, 0, 0, $m + 1, 0, 0 ) );`

Answer (score 2):

From the [`mktime()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php) docs there are (max) 6 parametes:
`hour, minute, seconds, month, day, year`

The following line:

```php
$month = date( 'F', mktime( 0, 0, 0, $m + 1, 0, 0, 0 ) );
```

Shows 7 params. You have one `0` to many, change it to:

```php
$month = date( 'F', mktime( 0, 0, 0, $m + 1, 0, 0 ) );
```

This well generate the following html:

```html
Birthday: 
<select name="month">
    <option value="0">Select Month</option>
    <option value="01">January</option>
    <option value="02">February</option>
    <option value="03">March</option>
    <option value="04">April</option>
    <option value="05">May</option>
    <option value="06">June</option>
    <option value="07">July</option>
    <option value="08">August</option>
    <option value="09">September</option>
    <option value="10">October</option>
    <option value="11">November</option>
    <option value="12">December</option>
</select>
```

as you can check in [this online demo](https://tio.run/##XVBha8IwEP3eX/EogpYGrH5cY2RD/TRhTL@XYDNSZppQ42AMf3t3SUeVPQK5u7x3dy9Ou75/aTqva/n9hIRf1FmdPFpp1Co1tvU6FQm3zje2xZc8X6lcpOIw0PaBwOfDM/HWTrsEhA/bzTAxWGFRhptTsAxRniPDT@QETNprIF18VzlZBwnDkqFgOBzfq7fnTfW63R2RlXdFXIo0tfRqhuluymA@fWMoKdjfoYk5FkOWParXYgwD/hmL@0OdtI2LlURPxWMxzg7lu@ex1ej9ltAUPh9@UvT9Lw).